# Как изменить переменную, по условию if...else.

Tags: php, mysql

Есть переменная "$dates". В html-форме есть DatePicker с именем "datetime".

Сейчас у меня код выглядит таким образом:

```
$dates = $_POST['datetime']; 
echo ($dates);
```

Как сделать так, если в форме DatePicker остается не заполненным, то переменная $dates принимает значение текущей даты.

Пытался делать так:

```
    if (isset($_POST["datetime"])) 
{

    $date1 = $_POST['datetime'];

} else 
{
  $date1 = now();
}
```

Не работает. 
Новичок в php, не бейте если сильно косячный код :Р

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может так

```
$dates='';
if(!empty($_POST['datetime'])){
$dates=$_POST['datetime'];
}else{
$dates=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Одну скобку забыли после:
if (!empty($_POST['datetime']))